# Compilation of project stucks while trying to compile one of the assets in Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, compilation, assets

I have a strange problem that I see for the 1st time in Unity. I'm trying to compile my project on Android platform. Other projects compile well but **this** is not.
The project consists of 1 scene with a few things, very simple. I've only imported 1 asset from the Unity store (it's explosion pack from unity).

Problem is when I start compilation, Unity stucks on one of the assets. And doesn't go further. Always the same number of the asset. But it's not asset's name, it's something else so I can't figure out what assets it exactly is. (I guess it's GUID but it gives me nothing).

What can I do with that and how could I know asset's name by that number?

[image]

p.s. In the Editor, everything works well.

Comment: And please guys tell me finally how to add screenshot in the post not like a link but exactly as a picture, still can't figure it out.)

Comment: You can't add screenshot because you are new and don't have enough reputation to do so. Answer questions or ask new question to get there

Answer (score 0):

If its really just a small project, try removing the assets and only include linke two vor three, test if it still works and then proceed with next few assets. Repeat until you found the falsy asset

Comment: But any way to find this asset by it's number displayed on the screenshot?